# Codeigniter Cookie issue for back end and front end side

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I developed one application in `Codeigniter` everything is going perfectly but I have one issue as follow:
I want to implement `autologin` to dashboard after first time login for both front end and back end.
**Explanation:** 
When I log in to `admin side` at first time it goes to `admin dashboard` and close `tab/browser` without clicking on `logout button` and put the `admin` link it goes to admin dashboard without login again, upto here everything is going well, but when I put `front end link (after first time login and closing tab)` it does not go to the `admin` dashboard and shows the error like

> The page isn't redirect properly

I faced this same problem at front end side.
I want to do this because it's a client requirement.
Please help me for this issue. Thanks.

Here is my index function

```
if($_COOKIE['AS_AD_SES_ADMIN_ID']!='' && $_COOKIE['stay_signedin']=='1')
{
        $username = $_COOKIE['ADMIN_USERNAME'];
        $password = $_COOKIE['ADMIN_PASS'];

        $result = $this->verifylogin->login($username, $password);

        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $sess_array = array(
                     'AS_AD_SES_ADMIN_ID'           =>  $row->fld_id,
                     'AS_AD_SES_ADMIN_FULL_NAME'    =>  $row->fld_user_name,
                     'AS_AD_SES_ADMIN_NAME'         =>  $row->fld_adm_name,
                     'AS_AD_SES_LOGIN_TIME'         =>  date('h:i:s A'),
                     'AS_AD_SES_LOGIN_DATE'         =>  date("d-m-Y"),
                     'AS_SES_ACCESS_LEVEL'          =>  $row->fld_access_level,
                     'AS_TAB_TITLE'                 =>  'Welcome to Project',
                     'logged_in'                    =>  TRUE
                   );

            $this->session->set_userdata($sess_array);
        }
        $this->load->view('dashboard');
}else{
        redirect(base_url());
}
```

Verifylogin models login function is as follows

```
function login($username, $password)
{
    $ip_address=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $this -> db -> select('fld_id, fld_user_name,fld_adm_name,fld_adm_pwd,fld_access_level');
    $this -> db -> from('tbl_admin');
    $this -> db -> where('fld_user_name',$username);
    $query = $this -> db -> get();

    if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
    {
        $res = $query->row();
        $pass = $res->fld_adm_pwd; 
        $pass1 = $this->encrypt->decode($pass); 
        if($pass1 == $password)
        {
            $password = $pass;

            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT fld_id,fld_user_name,fld_adm_name,fld_access_level,fld_adm_pwd,fld_stay_signed_in FROM tbl_admin where fld_user_name = '".$username."' and fld_adm_pwd = '".trim($password)."' and fld_isdeleted !=1 and fld_status = 'Active'");

            if($query->num_rows() == 1)
            {
              return $query->result();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: where is your code??

Comment: @saty thanks for instant reply, I used cookie for it when admin login then I set cookie for it.

Comment: we cant help you until we will not able to see your code?

Comment: ok, I will edit my question and put my code of admin side controller.

Comment: Why using un necessary foreach loop?

Comment: could you please share the code inside verifylogin::login ??

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is that $cookie is dieing when browser closed,
I suggest use $_SESSION variable.

```
// Start the session
session_start();

 if($_SESSION['AS_AD_SES_ADMIN_ID']!='' && $_SESSION['stay_signedin']=='1')
        {
            $username = $_SESSION['ADMIN_USERNAME'];
            $password = $_SESSION['ADMIN_PASS'];

            $result = $this->verifylogin->login($username, $password);

            foreach($result as $row)
            {
                $sess_array = array(
                         'AS_AD_SES_ADMIN_ID'           =>  $row->fld_id,
                         'AS_AD_SES_ADMIN_FULL_NAME'    =>  $row->fld_user_name,
                         'AS_AD_SES_ADMIN_NAME'         =>  $row->fld_adm_name,
                         'AS_AD_SES_LOGIN_TIME'         =>  date('h:i:s A'),
                         'AS_AD_SES_LOGIN_DATE'         =>  date("d-m-Y"),
                         'AS_SES_ACCESS_LEVEL'          =>  $row->fld_access_level,
                         'AS_TAB_TITLE'                 =>  'Welcome to Project',
                         'logged_in'                    =>  TRUE
                       );

                $this->session->set_userdata($sess_array);
            }
            $this->load->view('dashboard');
        }else{
            redirect(base_url());
        }
```

Comment: I want to implement the functionality like remember me in Codeigniter, for that I hve to use & set cookie for 2 weeks if user checks the remember me checkbox on login form.

Comment: set_userdata used for session variable, in your case for cookie you need to set cookie

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp ,Given about how to set cookie.

Answer (score 0):

If your `verifylogin->login` function will return false then also you are loading a dashboard view. You need to check if it return a false or result. And you don't need foreach for single result.

```
if($_COOKIE['AS_AD_SES_ADMIN_ID']!='' && $_COOKIE['stay_signedin']=='1')
{
    $username = $_COOKIE['ADMIN_USERNAME'];
    $password = $_COOKIE['ADMIN_PASS'];

    $row = $this->verifylogin->login($username, $password);

    if($row)
    {
        $sess_array = array(
                 'AS_AD_SES_ADMIN_ID'           =>  $row->fld_id,
                 'AS_AD_SES_ADMIN_FULL_NAME'    =>  $row->fld_user_name,
                 'AS_AD_SES_ADMIN_NAME'         =>  $row->fld_adm_name,
                 'AS_AD_SES_LOGIN_TIME'         =>  date('h:i:s A'),
                 'AS_AD_SES_LOGIN_DATE'         =>  date("d-m-Y"),
                 'AS_SES_ACCESS_LEVEL'          =>  $row->fld_access_level,
                 'AS_TAB_TITLE'                 =>  'Welcome to Project',
                 'logged_in'                    =>  TRUE
               );

        $this->session->set_userdata($sess_array);
        $this->load->view('dashboard');
    }else{
        redirect(base_url());
    }
}else{
    redirect(base_url());
}


function login($username, $password)
{
    $ip_address=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $this -> db->select('fld_id, fld_user_name,fld_adm_name,fld_adm_pwd,fld_access_level');
    $this -> db -> from('tbl_admin');
    $this -> db -> where('fld_user_name',$username);
    $query = $this -> db -> get();

    if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
    {
        $res = $query->row();
        $pass = $res->fld_adm_pwd; 
        $pass1 = $this->encrypt->decode($pass); 
        if($pass1 == $password)
        {
            $password = $pass;

            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT fld_id,fld_user_name,fld_adm_name,fld_access_level,fld_adm_pwd,fld_stay_signed_in FROM tbl_admin where fld_user_name = '".$username."' and fld_adm_pwd = '".trim($password)."' and fld_isdeleted !=1 and fld_status = 'Active'");

            if($query->num_rows() == 1)
            {
              return $query->row();
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```